# Find intersection of multiple DSM's using Python and GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, dem, intersection, batch

I am quite a beginner in respect to GIS and hopefully someone can help me out with the problem I have.

I have multiple digital surface models [DSMs] of the same area with all necessary geo-information (6 in total). However they are not exactly the same as they have been acquired on different days (row and cols of the raster are not identical). I already managed to align the DSMs, however now I need to find the intersecting area that is part of all six DSMs because I want to do some processing with this (which I indent to do in python).
I found the following post:

http://sciience.tumblr.com/post/101722591382/finding-the-georeferenced-intersection-between-two

This methods works fine for two DSMs, however the extension to more areas is not straightforward (at least not for me at the moment).

I guess this is a rather standard beginner problem, however I only ever found answers regarding exactly two areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reclassify the six surface models so that all the elevation data values equal one and the non-data pixels equal 0.
Multiply the 6 reclassified outputs together.  The resulting  raster will contain values of one or zero.  Anyplace the output has a value of one will be that place where all six surface share data values.

[Here is a GDAL link to get you started.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116473/reclassifying-rasters-using-gdal-and-python)

[Here is a link to the reclassify tool in ArcGIS.](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm)

[And here is a QGIS solution.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17712/performing-raster-reclassification-in-qgis)

If you are interested in a Python solution you should still work it out in GIS first.  Consider learning Model Builder in ArcGIS then export your model to Python once you have it working.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer!

I will have a look at ArcGIS and QGIS. However creating a binary mask would not work in my case, as the elevations can be quite sparse and would be even sparser with that appraoch. However for future reference I found a very quick and easy work-around: use gdal_merge.py with the seperate option (join each raster in a different band). This automatically does what I want and I can read each band separately afterwards!