# Classify DEM pixels

Tags: gdal, dem, gdal-calc

I have a differential surface model dataset. That was made: DSM subtracted from DTM, so for example trees have negative height. It is a raster (TIFF) dataset, Type=Float32.

I want to create a shapefile that will have three different values:

- 0: error (all the pixels in the original dataset with values > 0)
- 1: OK (all the pixels in the original dataset with values < 0)
- 2: nodata (all the pixels in the original dataset with values = -10000000000)

I assume first thing to create a raster with pixel values 0, 1, 2 only and than vectorize it. Probably the vectorization will not be a problem, using `gdal_polygonize.py` but creating the raster is quite a challenge for me, although I was able to achieved some minor success using `gdal_calc`.

I'd like to do this using GDAL, do you have an idea?

Comment: This type of operation is called a reclassification.  There is a reclassification tool in ArcGIS but you would need a spatial analyst license.  QGIS (free) has a Reclassify by table tool or you can use SAGA in QGIS to reclassify rasters.  If you want to only use GDAL I found this link https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116473/reclassifying-rasters-using-gdal-and-python.  Good luck.

Comment: You can achieve this with gdal_calc and gdal_polygonize. If you want actual help, you should post what you've tried with gdal_calc and your results--i.e. describe what you mean by "minor success." If you use gdal within Python, you can just load the raster in as a numpy array and do the classification with numpy slicing, although you will need some extra coding to re-save as a geotiff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `gdal` python bindings to read the array and then `numpy` to change the pixel values. Then you can use `gdal` again to overwrite your original raster.

```
import gdal

fn = 'path_to_your_raster.tif'
ds = gdal.Open(fn, 1)   # open TIFF file in writing mode
arr = ds.ReadAsArray()  # read the data as a numpy array

# specify your conditions
con1 = (arr > 0)
con2 = (arr < 0)
con3 = (arr == -10000000000)

# change values according to the conditions
arr[con1] = 0
arr[con2] = 1
arr[con3] = 2

# overwrite the TIFF data
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
band.WriteArray(arr)

# save file and close
ds.FlushCache()
del ds, band
```

Comment: As far as I understand 'numpy' is installed correctly (based on [this](https://datanitro.com/blog/python_on_windows)) but when I try to run your script I got several error messages: 
"ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import", 
"ImportError: No module named _gdal_array"

Comment: What Python version do you have? And is it a stand alone Python installation or are you using and installation that came with another programm (e.g. QGIS)?

Comment: v2.7 came with ArcGIS I think, but I have QGIS as well v 3.2.3

Comment: @STO Can you try to run this script in the QGIS Python console? The Python installation that comes with ArcMap does not include GDAL.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use R, it's `raster` package supports intuitive raster algebra that will make your task very simple.  Try this:

```
library(raster)

rred <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))[['red']] ## MWE, use your data
values(rred) <- values(rred) - mean(values(rred))

rbad <- rred > 0
rgood <- rred <= 0
rmiss <- rred == -100 ## please use your true value of -10e9, this is only for MWE

writeRaster(rgood, filename='good.tif')
writeRaster(rbad, filename='bad.tif')
## etc
```

now polygonize them with GDAL, if you wish.  Alternatively install and load `gdalUtils` and do it all inside R.  The `raster` package can do polygonization too, but it's insufferably slow.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is "R". Can you give me a link?

Comment: Certainly.  R was designed as a statistical computing language, and it's grown to be a capable GIS too.  Download it [here](https://www.r-project.org/).  It's package management is also superior to most--install the `raster` package with `install.packages("raster")`  Load packages up like `library(raster)`